# PyMC3: RuntimeError in Spyder

Tags: spyder, pymc3

I am learning to use PyMC3. However, whenever I try to run an MCMC simulation in Spyder 4.0.0 , I get the following RuntimeError:

> RuntimeError: The communication pipe between the main process and its
>   spawned children is broken. In Windows OS, this usually means that the
>   child process raised an exception while it was being spawned, before
>   it was setup to communicate to the main process. The exceptions raised
>   by the child process while spawning cannot be caught or handled from
>   the main process, and when running from an IPython or jupyter notebook
>   interactive kernel, the child's exception and traceback appears to be
>   lost. A known way to see the child's error, and try to fix or handle
>   it, is to run the problematic code as a batch script from a system's
>   Command Prompt. The child's exception will be printed to the Command
>   Promt's stderr, and it should be visible above this error and
>   traceback. Note that if running a jupyter notebook that was invoked
>   from a Command Prompt, the child's exception should have been printed
>   to the Command Prompt on which the notebook is running.

As an example, I am using a copy-paste from the first example of the PyMC3 'Getting Started' tutorial (https://docs.pymc.io/notebooks/getting_started.html), however I seem to get this error no matter which model I use. I only get an error when running the `pm.sample()` function line. I have tried using a new virtual environment, and even removing and reinstalling Python/Anaconda from my computer. Interestingly, when I run the programme in Jupyter - it works. Any ideas what's going on?

```
# True parameter values
alpha, sigma = 1, 1
beta = [1, 2.5]

# Size of dataset
size = 100

# Predictor variable
X1 = np.random.randn(size)
X2 = np.random.randn(size) * 0.2

# Simulate outcome variable
Y = alpha + beta[0]*X1 + beta[1]*X2 + np.random.randn(size)*sigma

basic_model = pm.Model()
with basic_model:

    # Priors for unknown model parameters
    alpha = pm.Normal('alpha', mu=0, sigma=10)
    beta = pm.Normal('beta', mu=0, sigma=10, shape=2)
    sigma = pm.HalfNormal('sigma', sigma=1)

    # Expected value of outcome
    mu = alpha + beta[0]*X1 + beta[1]*X2

    # Likelihood (sampling distribution) of observations
    Y_obs = pm.Normal('Y_obs', mu=mu, sigma=sigma, observed=Y)

with basic_model:
    # draw 500 posterior samples
    trace = pm.sample(500)
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
with basic_model:
    # draw 500 posterior samples
    trace = pm.sample(500, cores=1)
```